# How does Newton's First Law uphold in this case?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, collision, free-body-diagram

Let say that there is no air drag. A ball is thrown towards me and I hit it with a bat. Here of course I apply some force in hitting it. Then can someone help me out by explaining how does the ball obey first law over the course of its motion.

Answer (score 2):

Newton's first law of motion states:

> Every object will remain at rest or in uniform motion in a straight line unless compelled to change its state by the action of an external force.

The ball was initially at rest. Then it was thrown towards you. So someone applied a force on the ball towards your direction, which compelled the ball to change its state of motion, from rest to a state of constant non-zero velocity (assuming there is no drag and we are only interested in the forces acting on the ball in the horizontal plane).

When you hit it with a bat, you apply a force on it in another direction (not that of its motion). So you change its direction of motion and possibly, also its speed.

Hence, on the application of an external force in both these cases, the state of rest or uniform motion of the ball is changed.

**Here it is important to note that "a state of rest or uniform motion in a straight line" refers to a condition where the body has a constant velocity i.e., both the direction of motion and the speed of the body remain constant (rest = constant velocity of $0$ m/s).**

Comment: You should also account for gravity

Comment: @BobD In the answer I read *assuming there is no drag and we are only interested in the forces acting on the ball in the horizontal plane.* There is no gravity in the horizontal plane.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I believe that was added that as an edit after my comment

Comment: Just one more thing.if we ignore gravity here and assume ball travels in a 2D plane then after initial application of force via the bat there is no external force acting on the ball.Is it right to say that now it moves with a constant velocity of V? Then what about the acceleration provided at the instant the force is applied?

Comment: @KyledeBrunne  the force provides an initial acceleration which initiates the change in velocity. After that if force stops working (as is the case in your qs) the ball attains a constant velocity

Comment: @KyledeBrunne N1 states, "*If no force acts on the ball,* then the ball moves with constant velocity". If a force does act on the ball (like the contact force from the bat onto the ball), then N1 does not apply to the situation.

Answer (score 1):

When you hit the ball, you apply a force to it which changes its velocity. If there were no other forces, then the ball would travel in a straight line at a constant speed. However, there is gravity, which continues to accelerate the ball downwards, so that eventually the ball hits the ground.

When you hit the ball, you can consider its velocity as having a vertical and horizontal component. Since the force of gravity applies vertically, the horizontal component is unaffected and will remain unchanged in accordance with NFL, assuming we ignore air resistance.

If the ball starts with an upward vertical component of velocity, the force of gravity will act to reduce that gradually until the ball comes to be momentarily at rest in the vertical direction; thereafter it will accelerate downwards. The combination of the constant horizontal component of velocity and the continuously accelerated vertical component results in the overall parabolic shape of the ball's trajectory.